# Pass function to class and set a class function to the function passed in

Tags: c++, class, function-pointers

I'm trying to pass a function into a class and set a class function to the function that was passed in.

Button.h

```
class Button
{
public:
    Button(void(*onClick)());
    ~Button();

    void onClick();
}
```

Button.cpp

```
#include "Button.h"

Button::Button(void(*onClick)())
{
    this->onClick = onClick;
}
```

When I try to compile it I get

> a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function

Comment: `void onClick();` should be something like `void (*onClick)();`. You clearly already know how to declare pointers to function - you did it for the constructor's parameter. So declare your data member the same way.

Comment: That's not how it works.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I just tried that and it does not work.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What outcome do you expect, and what do you observe instead? Show the code you are currently compiling, and any error messages it produces.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Nevermind it worked thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a function pointer or `std::function` :

#### Function pointer:

```cpp
using void_func_ptr = void (*) ();

void_func_ptr = other_function;
```

#### `std::function`:

```cpp
auto void_func_ptr = std::bind(other_function);
```